# How to change this script to have a max character limit instead of a min?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, unbounce

I am working on a form in Unbounce and need the name fields to have a max character limit. I found this script in the Unbounce community but can't seem to get the modifications to work for a max limit instead of a min. Can someone help me with what changes I need to make. Thanks!

```
<script>
  window.ub.form.customValidators.characterminlimit = {
    isValid: function(value) {
        return /^(?=.{50,})/.test(value);
    },
    message: 'Enter min 50 character',
  };
</script>

<script>
  window.ub.form.validationRules.first_name.characterminlimit = true;
</script>
```

Comment: `value.length < 50`?

Comment: `return !/^(?=.{50,})/.test(value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you can't get the length for the string `value`, you can try this regex `/(^.{1,50}$)/` instead of the one you're currently using. This will only match strings between 1 and 50 characters.

Comment: The script OP posted checks if a string is longer than 50 characters. OP wants a script that checks if string is 50 characters at most

Comment: @KonradLinkowski replacing the regex in OPs script with this one should achieve the result they are looking for based on my testing. Do you disagree? Edit: Glad I could help mac!